# PostgreSQL JSONB (Selecting value returns value with quotes, "value")

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Have a JSONB column with data like this:

```
{"title": "Some book!", "uniqueId": "11264299-2543-566"}
```

When I try to select the values, they are returned with double quotes surrounding them...

```
SELECT 'Some book!', json_data->'title' FROM myJsonTable
```

Returns:

```
Some book!      "Some book!"
```

Comment: on phone: SELECT 'Some book!', json_data->>'title' FROM myJsonTable; notice the double arrow, single -> returns type JSON where strings are quoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using json_data->'title', I needed to use jsonb_extract_path_text(json_data, 'title')...

Edit: Or as Lucas said in the comment, use json_data->>'title'...